# Use shell:Programs in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, python-os

In windows you can use windows + r and type shell:Programs. Im trying to use this in my python script.

I have tryed doing this.

```
import os
path = os.getenv('shell:Programs')
```

and

```
from os import path
path = os.path.expandvars('shell:Programs')
```

This sadly only works for tags like %appdata%

Help!

Comment: What do you want to achieve, to open file explorer using script?

If that is you want to do, I've posted the answer else let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os
os.startfile('shell:Programs')
```

*OR*

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("explorer")
#with file path    
#subprocess.call("explorer C:\\")
```

Comment: Coud i store the full path in a variabel?

Comment: Yes, Try this `path = 'C:\\'`
`subprocess.call("explorer "+path)`